# Get stacktrace for Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to get stack trace for my error to see where the app went wrong.

In my Cordova Android app, I am using Canvas in my javascript file to draw things when user drags the screen.

Sometimes, but not always, I get

```
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: 1.1.9
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: 101098
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: 45012863-7d3b-4c30-8ccf-e65394c57d85
11-19 13:57:07.022 13389-13451/myApp W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
11-19 13:57:07.023 13389-13451/myApp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x338 in tid 13451 (GpuThread)
```

Note that it does not show the stack trace. I also tried to keep my chrome inspector open when the error happens, but I see no error in the console.

This did not happen when I was testing with KitKat. It happens on Marshmallow.

I've tried to disable `android:hardwareAccelerated` but that is not an option for me because the app gets incredibly slow. How can I get the stack trace, and any idea why I am getting this?

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling System WebView Updates. This seems working for me.